# reduce comma separated array to string using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to convert the array of response to comma separated string or number. Is there any possible way to do this? 
Actual data: `[521,221,623]`

Expecting data:  **521,221,623** or **'521','221','623'**

I tried my best. But I was not able to achieve. Any suggestion or advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use Array.join(",")

Comment: Read about [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

Comment: try these in console : `[521,221,623].toString()` or `[521,221,623].join(', ')` or `[521,221,623].join()`.

Comment: `alert([1,2,3])` ?!

Comment: so you want a single string as result?

Comment: yes . I am expecting single string @alfredopacino

Comment: methods which you have commented wont work @Karan

Answer (score 2):

Use `Array.join()`

```js
const x = [521,221,623];
console.log("'"+x.join("','")+"'");
```

Comment: @musefan well what is so awful about this answer? Or what is the asked question if you care to explain you different point of view?

Comment: i tried `join` but i am getting the response like this: "521,221"

Comment: @SRK In your question, as you have said `Expecting data: 521,221,623 or '521','221','623'`. Isnt the answer same as the first one?

Comment: your snippet is correct, but in my terminal. I am not getting the expected answer. After trying so many condition , i posted this question @void

Comment: @SRK can you exactly write here what you are expecting?

Comment: this is what I am expecting : `'521','221','623'` @void

Comment: I updated your logic in my code. This is what i got `"'521','221'"`

Comment: i need to remove that double quoted string @void

Comment: @SRK as it is a string the double quotes are just there for the representation. If you will use this value somewhere then it wont be there...

Comment: The logic what you have given will always accept the string. I am passing those values in my bindparameter. So i looking for answer without double quotes

Answer (score 1):

To get the string 521,221,623

```js
var arr = [521,221,623]; // your array
var str = arr.join(","); // join each element of array with a separator 
console.log(str); // check it in console
```

To get the second string '521','221','623'

```js
var arr = [521,221,623]; // your original array.
var newArr = arr.map( (num)=> { return "'" + num + "'" }).join(","); // map is used to iterate each element and manipulate if needed
console.log(newArr);
```

API ref : [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: @kiranvj. The answer what you have suggested is correct. But I don't, why it's not working for me. Still I am getting response has: **'521,221,623'**

Comment: @SRK can you post your full code or create a fiddle

Comment: @SRK but first character of that string is `5`, not `'`

Answer (score 1):

```
const res = [521,221,623].map(x => `'${x}'`).join(',')
```

```js
const res = [521,221,623].map(x => `'${x}'`).join(',')
console.log(res);
```